# Best framework and best practice for OAuth2.0 auth-server and provider implementation?

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, cxf

I have some rest-service (simple fileuploader) on scala play and now we need protect this with oauth2 protocol.

I try found any scala oauth2-frameworks but they not supported implicit flow. I decided use java for ouath2 server but now i can't decide which framework should i choose. I have a choice between Spring Security OAuth and Apache CXF OAuth.

I never work with this frameworks and hope that someone more experienced can give me any advices and help in choice.

**EDIT:**
So, if nobody want spend own time for explanation for me, maybe you can show any examples of implementation oauth2 with both frameworks?

Comment: I am also in the phase of looking for a server side java library to implement OAuth 2.0 and came across this comparison list - http://dreamworldsolutions.com/blog/2014/12/13/oauth-2-0-providers/. Open Context also seems to be in list.